# More complex criteria for SUMIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm not sure whether this is complex but can I write the sumif for items that falls under a certain subset without listing the respective subset alongside the item.

For example I want to know the total amount if its in subset 1, without doing an indexmatch beside each of the items in sheet 1. Thank you!


Sheet 1:
 Item     Amount 
A                   £ 
B                   £ 
C                   £ 
A                   £ 
C                   £ 
D                   £ 
D                   £ 
E                   £ 

Sheet 2: 

  Item     Subset 
A                   1 
B                   2 
C                   1 
D                   3 
E                   1

Answer (score 1):

A sumifs inside a sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,E1:E5)*(F1:F5=I1))
```

[image]